# How to extract values from subprocess.run json output command

Tags: python, json, subprocess

I am trying to assign the values to the variable from the subprocess.run() command
my code below

```
import subprocess
import_json_names = 'fileb://xxx/yyyy.json'

output = subprocess.run(['aws', 'apigateway', 'import-rest-api', '--body', f'{import_json_names}', '--profile', 'xxxx'],capture_output=True,
  text=True, check=True)
finaloutput = output.stdout
print(finaloutput)
```

after execute the above command, I m getting the following output

```
{
    "id": "123abc444",
    "name": "xxxx",
    "description": "xxx yy",
    "createdDate": "2022-06-06T13:41:44+05:30",
    "version": "2021-05-31T18:09:59Z",
    "apiKeySource": "HEADER",
    "endpointConfiguration": {
        "types": [
            "EDGE"
        ]
    },
    "disableExecuteApiEndpoint": false
}
```

I want to extract "id" values from the above output
how to achieve the same?

Comment: you have to translate `finaloutput` as a python dictionary using the `json` module in python, specifically `json.loads()`

Comment: try `print(json.loads(finaloutput)["id"])`

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example, I just echo'd a JSON object but it should work with your subprocess call too. (I added the extra `shell` argument to `run` for the demo but you can just ignore it for your use case.)

```py
import subprocess
import json


output = subprocess.run(
    'echo {"id": "Woderick"}',
    capture_output=True,
    text=True,
    check=True,
    shell=True  # extra parameter for echo demo
)
print(output.stdout)
output_dict = json.loads(output.stdout)
print(output_dict["id"])
```

Comment: Note that [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) can be used to cover the capture and check options In a more concise form.